# mysql 5.1.59 won't start on Mac OS 10.7 at startup

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

When I reboot, mysql 5.1.59 is not running despite Activity Monitor showing 2 mysql PIDs. IF I quit the 2 mysql instances, I am able to startup mysql in Webmin (working PID is 3735, see below).

When I run this in Terminal: ps axu | grep mysql

I get:

root            3261   0.0  0.0  2435492    932   ??  Ss    9:52AM   0:00.03 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql

admin1          3843   0.0  0.0  2435492    348 s000  R+    9:56AM   0:00.00 grep mysql

_mysql          3735   0.0  0.3  2522936  13680   ??  S     9:53AM   0:00.04 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/macpro.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/macpro.local.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306

Why do there seem to be 3 instances (3 users) here?

I assumed that my file:

com.mysql.mysql.plist

in

Library/LaunchDaemons

would be the only method that mysql launches at startup. I do not use the mysql PrefPane (never worked anyway), nor are there any mysql items in Library/StartupItems.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
<string>--user=mysql</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: above is the contents of the file com.mysql.mysql.plist